# In Python Jupyter notebook, how to select an option from the combobox and click the "Print" button to print in the Chrome browser console?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, pyqt5, qwebengineview

I'm using Python in Jupyter notebook and Chrome browser, coding pyqt5 app. In some parts of the code, I need to use QWebEngineView for HTML Combobox widget ( not using Qcombox() ). The next code is when select an option from the combobox and click the "Print Selected Value" button, the selected value should be printed in the browser console. However, no value printed when click on the button. How can fix this issue?

The code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView    
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

html = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTML ComboBox</title>
    <script>
        function printSelectedValue() {
            var combobox = document.getElementById("myComboBox");
            var selectedValue = combobox.value;
            console.log("Selected Value: " + selectedValue);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="myComboBox">
        <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
    </select>

    <button onclick="printSelectedValue()">Print Selected Value</button>
</body>
</html>
"""


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
web_engine_view = QWebEngineView()
web_engine_view.setHtml(html)
web_engine_view.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```